# Using typeid with templates

Tags: c++, string, templates

```
template<class T>
inline T Library<T>::get_isbn()
{
    T temp;
    cout << "Enter the name/no:" << endl;
    cin >> temp;
    string ka;
    if (typeid(temp) == typeid(ka))
    {
        while (islower(temp[0]))
        {
            cout << " Pls enter the using the first letter as capital" << endl;
            cin >> temp;
        }
    }
}
return temp;
}
```

I'm creating a template class which can take either integer or `string` as template parameter and when I create an object of the class with `T` as `string`, it's going in the loop and everything's works fine. But when I create an object with `int` as template parameter, it gives me following two errors:

> error C1903: unable to recover from previous error(s); stopping
>   compilation
>
> error C2228: left of '.at' must have class/struct/union

I want that if parameter passed is `string`, then only the code for checking the first alphabet to be capital should run, else when I give the template parameter as `int`, it shouldn't check for the first alphabet thing.

Comment: After formatting, you seem to have too many closing braces `}`.

Comment: Your code does not contain calls to at() so you did not post actual code.

Comment: This is now possible with if_constexpr. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69375132/how-can-i-use-different-struct-as-template-argument-in-a-template-function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An `if` in C++ is always (semantically) a run-time decision. It *may* be evaluated by the compiler at compile-time, and the unused branch thrown away. But it *may* doesn't mean it *must*. You still have to ensure all branches contain valid code.

In this example, the expression `temp[0]` is ill-formed if `temp` is an integer. The simplest solution would be to call an overloaded function inside your generic function -- note: by introducing a `typeid`-branching, your algorithm inherently isn't generic any more, it requires special treatment for some types.

```
template<class T>
void get_isbn_impl(T&)
{
    // default implementation
}

void get_isbn_impl(string& str)
{
    // special version for `string`
    while (islower(str[0]))
    {
        cout << " Pls enter the using the first letter as capital" << endl;
        cin >> str;
    }
}

template<class T>
inline T Library<T>::get_isbn()
{
    T temp;
    cout << "Enter the name/no:" << endl;
    cin >> temp;

    get_isbn_impl(temp);

    return temp;
}
```

It is also possible to specialize either `Library<string>` (the whole class) or just `Library<string>::get_isbn`.

Answer (score 0):

The [typeid](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid) is not a [constexpr](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr), so it cannot impact on the template content during compilation stage. All stuff must be compiled.

C++ 17 has introduced [if constexpr](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if) statement, so it is possible to define  a function in a similar way to your example:

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <cctype>
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template<class T>
inline T get_isbn()
{
    T temp;
    std::cout << "Enter the name/no:" << std::endl;
    std::cin >> temp;
    std::string ka;
    // if (typeid(temp) == typeid(ka)) // It is not a constexpr.
    
    // if constexpr compiles only when condition is met.
    
    // Passing types directly to std::is_same
    // if constexpr (std::is_same<T, std::string>::value)
    
    // Deducing types using decltype()
    if constexpr (std::is_same<decltype(temp), decltype(ka)>::value)
    {
        while (std::islower(temp[0]))
        {
            std::cout << " Pls enter the using the first letter as capital" << std::endl;
            std::cin >> temp;
        }
    }
    return temp;
}

int main()
{
    const auto isbn_int = get_isbn<int>();
    std::cout << "The ISBN<int> is: ["<< isbn_int << "]" << std::endl;
    
    const auto isbn_string = get_isbn<std::string>();
    std::cout << "The ISBN<string> is: ["<< isbn_string << "]" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}

// Sample input/output:
// Enter the name/no:
// 123
// The ISBN<int> is: [123]
// Enter the name/no:
// My-ISBN-Number 
// The ISBN<string> is: [My-ISBN-Number]
```

Before C++17, you must use template specialization, as [@dyp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/420683/dyp) mentioned.

Comment: [`std::type_info::operator==`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support/23) becomes `constexpr` in C++23.

Comment: Ok, I didn't find it in documentation, but even if `operator==` is `constexpr`, operator typeid() still isn't `constexpr` - because it recognizes polymorphic types, not known during compilation stage.

Comment: I believe this only matters if you apply it to a reference to a polymorphic type. Otherwise it should work at compile-time (otherwise what would be the point of the constexpr `==`).