# How can I use different struct as template argument in a template function?

Tags: c++, templates, struct, c++17, function-templates

I am writing a template function like that:

```cpp
template<typename T>
std::string EncodeData(int DataType, T Data, std::string ReadCommandID, std::string& ThisID);
```

The type `T` that I want to use is some different structs, for example:

```cpp
struct A
{
    int A_data;
    bool A_data_2;
    // etc.......
};

struct B
{
    double B_data;
    char B_data_2;
    // etc.......
};
```

I want the function can access different member variables depends on different `struct` passing to `T`,so I wrote such code:

```cpp
template<typename T>
std::string EncodeData(int DataType, T Data, std::string ReadCommandID, std::string& ThisID)
{
    if(std::is_same<T, A>{})
    {
        // Do something with Data.A_data and Data.A_data_2
    }
    else if(std::is_same<T, B>{})
    {
        // Do something with Data.B_data and Data.B_data_2
    }
    // other code.
}
```

And use it:

```cpp
A data={100,false};
std::string id;
std::string result = EncodeData<A>(0,data,"read_id_xxxxxxxx",id);
```

But when I compile it, the following error happened:

```
error C2039: "B_data": is not a member of "A".    
error C2039: "B_data_2": is not a member of "A".
```

How can I fix this? Or what else I can do to solve this problem in one single function?

P.S. *I'm using MSVC Compiler(Visual Studio 2019)*

Comment: You want to specialize your template for different `T`. Search for that term and you will find instructions and examples galore.

Comment: or [constexpr if](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if)

Comment: Also your problem seems to me not good to be solvable via templates. Maybe use the visitor pattern instead

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Or just make two overloads. Specializing function templates might be [tricky](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill17.htm).

Comment: what works best depends on whether you need to call it only with 2 different types, or there are actually more (and then still it depends whether the number of types is considerably small or should be unbounded)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> What else I can do to slove this problom in **one single function**?

This is not possible under [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11) compiler. However, in C++17 you have [`if constexpr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if#Constexpr_if) to do such:

```
template<typename T>
std::string EncodeData(int DataType, T const& Data, std::string const& ReadCommandID, std::string& ThisID)
{
    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, A>)
    {
        // Do something with Data.A_data and Data.A_data_2
    }
    else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, B>)
    {
        // Do something with Data.B_data and Data.B_data_2
    }
}
```

For C++11 you still need two functions. Therefore, I would suggest having a function overload for each, which might be more readable than having templates.

Comment: I added the `c++11` label by mistake.  This is the way I need, Thanks!